# Elasticsearch filter increases results instead of reducing them

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build the following filter logic:

```
at least one geolocation must be truthy
AND
The status must be equal to 1.
```

Right now when I add the term query for status the number of results increases, where as it is expected for it to be the same.
All records in the sample index I am using have status equal to 1.

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "status": "1"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "should":[
                  {
                     "geo_distance":{
                        "distance":"24km",
                        "locations":{
                           "lat":11.11,
                           "lon":13.52
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "geo_distance":{
                        "distance":"24km",
                        "locations":{
                           "lat":81.11,
                           "lon":43.52
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do two things.

**Filter + Should** (I would choose)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "24km",
            "locations": {
              "lat": 11.11,
              "lon": 13.52
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "24km",
            "locations": {
              "lat": 81.11,
              "lon": 43.52
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Use **[minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match)**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "24km",
            "locations": {
              "lat": 11.11,
              "lon": 13.52
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "24km",
            "locations": {
              "lat": 81.11,
              "lon": 43.52
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: These are correct solutions, though I'd like to add a bit of explanation. The thing is that `should` and `must` only behave like `OR` and `AND` when they are the only clause in the `bool`. If `bool` contains *both* `should` and `must` it means "all of the MUST clauses AND *zero or more* should clauses". `filter` and `minimum_should_match` allow to "fix" this.